# Как правильно указать путь сохранения к файлу?

Tags: c++

Интересует правильная возможность назначения пути к папки, в релизной версии программы.

Сейчас я указываю путь так

`file1 = "doc/" + "save.txt"`

`file2 = "doc/2019/" + to_string(num);`

но скорее всего это не правильно.

Еще интересует доступ к моим документам в windows и как обычно там создают папку, тоже интересно.

Comment: *"как обычно там создают папку"* Какую папку? Ничего не понятно. Можете подробнее объяснить?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нет не создавать а указать путь, как правильно указать путь в коде к уже созданной папки и файлу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы указываете относительный путь, то он расчитывается относительно базового пути приложения, который можно получить / изменить функциями:
[GetCurrentDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory)
[SetCurrentDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory)

Получение пути к папке windows:
[GetWindowsDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectorya)

Получение путей к служебным папкам windows:
[SHGetFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) - deprecated (xp support)
[SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) - vista+

Пример для получения моих документов:
SHGetFolderPath:

```
CHAR my_doc_path[MAX_PATH] { 0 };
HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, my_doc_path);
// my_doc_path = C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents
```

SHGetKnownFolderPath:

```
PWSTR ppszPath { nullptr };

HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &ppszPath);
// ppszPath = C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents
...
CoTaskMemFree(ppszPath); // не забыть освободить память
```

UPD1:
Для рекурсивного создания пути (когда одна или несколько подпапок могут не существовать) используется функция [SHCreateDirectoryEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shcreatedirectoryexa)

Comment: А то что я дальше путь указываю "doc/" это правильно?

Comment: @zip, ну это уже ваш выбор, как правило в "моих документах" создается папка с именем = имени приложения, куда уже сохраняются документы, настройки большинство приложений сохраняют в папку AppData\Roaming\<app_name> текущего (или всех) пользователя

Comment: @zip, для склейки путей лучше пользуйтесь средствами std::filesystem::path

Comment: Пока не совсем понимаю как все работает, мало информации, запутано все.
Например я хочу сделать путь для операционных систем windows 7 и 10
путь будет таким `C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents\doc\2019`
какой должен быть код в правильной форме.

Comment: Еще заинтересовался, как вы указывайте путь app_name

Comment: @zip, никак, работаю с абсолютными путями

Comment: А как можно проверить существует папка или нет?

Comment: @zip давайте решать вопросы по-одному) задавайте новый, вам ответят